# PHP read CSV file till tab space

Tags: php

I have a CSV file whose contents are as below.

**1 2 3 4 \t 45 56 67**

As seen above, after the value 4, I have a tab space. I need to read the values only till tab space. I am able to open the CSV file and read till tab delimiter as below.

```
$file = fopen("outputfile.csv","r");
//I am reading till tab space.
while ($line = fgetcsv($file, 0, "\t") !== false)
```

However, now I need to read all the values till tab space into PHP array for some manipulation. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Have you heard about [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
while ($line = fgetcsv($file, 0, "\t") !== false) {
    $columns = str_getcsv($line, ' '); //or use explode()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

explode() is the way to go.

```
$file = fopen("outputfile.csv","r");
while ($line = fgetcsv($file, 0, "\t") !== false)
{
    $array = explode(' ', $line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split the line into "before tab" and "after tab" components, and only do the parsing on the "before tab" half:

```
$file = fopen("outputfile.csv","r");

// for each line in the file, until EOF
while( ($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    // split out the tab char:
    $beforeTab = explode( "\t", $line)[0];
    // now, parse the CSV part
    $parsedCSV = str_getcsv( $beforeTab);
    // do what you need with the parsedCSV array.
}
```

Comment: Note I'm assuming you actually have a CSV file, and not what you displayed in your question (which is not a CSV file).